# CSS Compass project fails to locate @import "compass";

Tags: sass, atom-editor, compass

**The Problem:**

I am updating a website that was created using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/install/). I installed Compass and then ran the following command to set up Compass with my existing project. Next I imported Compass into my global.scss file. [SASS-Autocompile](https://github.com/armin-pfaeffle/sass-autocompile) *(a package for the text editor [Atom](https://atom.io/))* fails to locate the file and throws a compilation error. I am not sure if this is an issue with the set up of compass or if it is a problem with SASS-Autocompile. Here are the steps I took which led up to this point.

```
compass create --sass-dir "scss" --css-dir "css" --images-dir "images"
```

**Output:**

```
*********************************************************************
Congratulations! Your compass project has been created.

You may now add and edit sass stylesheets in the scss subdirectory of your project.

Sass files beginning with an underscore are called partials and won't be
compiled to CSS, but they can be imported into other sass stylesheets.

You can configure your project by editing the config.rb configuration file.

You must compile your sass stylesheets into CSS when they change.
This can be done in one of the following ways:
  1. To compile on demand:
     compass compile [path/to/project]
  2. To monitor your project for changes and automatically recompile:
     compass watch [path/to/project]

More Resources:
  * Website: http://compass-style.org/
  * Sass: http://sass-lang.com
  * Community: http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/


To import your new stylesheets add the following lines of HTML (or equivalent) to your webpage:
<head>
  <link href="/css/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE]>
      <link href="/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**global.scss**

```
@import "compass";
```

**Terminal:** *(while in project root dir)*

```
compass compile
```

**Output:**

```
  warning Webkit only supports pixels for the start and end stops for radial gradients. Got: 70%
    write css/global.css
```

Then I save my global.scss file which runs SASS-Autocompile and this error is presented.

***SASS-Autocompile: Compiliation Error***

```
{
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
  Parent style sheet: /Users/robby/Documents/reseminary/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dev.reseminary.edu/scss/global.scss",
}
```

Comment: I don't think you require the colon (:) in `@import: "compass";`. Also, as per the error, its obvious that you don't have the file `compass.scss` to import. Is that what you really want to import?

Comment: @GibinEalias I think I do need the `;` and I have no idea if that's what I need to import. Every online tutorial tells me to do it. But I have no idea where `compass.scss` is actually stored. I can't figure it out everything looks like it is properly configured.

Comment: I was talking about the colon (`:`) and not the semi-colon (`;`)

Comment: @GibinEalias oh you're right, sorry I read that wrong. in my `global.scss` file I do have it as `@import "compass";`